# Python Regex to match text ending on new line in source code

Tags: python, regex

I have Smarty template code. Using Python re, I want to match the entire if conditions if its split on a new line. The objective is to remove all if conditions.

```
{if true eq isset( $username ) and false eq $is_logged and false}
{if true eq isset( $username ) 
and false eq $is_logged and false}

{if true eq isset( $username ) and $boolLoggedIn}
    Hello {$username}
{/if}

{if true eq isset( $username )}
    {assign var=username value=$fname}
{/if}
```

I tried with below regex, but it matches only if the entire if the condition is on a single line.

```
    {(if|/if)(.)*(?<=})
```

Fiddle:
https://regex101.com/r/dVTgla/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `.` to match everything (and it does not match newline, at least by default), a better approach might be to match everything-except-close-brace: `[^}]`. You can also simplify the regex a fair bit.

```
import re

TEXT = '''
{if true eq isset( $username ) and false eq $is_logged and false}
{if true eq isset( $username ) 
and false eq $is_logged and false}

{if true eq isset( $username ) and $boolLoggedIn}
    Hello {$username}
{/if}

{if true eq isset( $username )}
    {assign var=username value=$fname}
{/if}
'''

rgx = re.compile(r'{/?if[^}]*}')

for m in rgx.findall(TEXT):
    print()
    print(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
({\/?if[\s\S]*(?<=}))
```

The reason `.*` isn't working is because it captures everything BUT a line terminator. Check out the [documentation here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)